# What's the difference between using backbone, jquery as commonjs module in node and using them in script tag?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, browserify, commonjs

I want to use browserify to bundle frontend libraries. So I need to require backbone and jquery as dependencies. But it doesn't work if I simply require them. I have to explicitly set  Backbone.$ to jquery:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
```

And some thread says that for jquery to work correctly, I need to explicitly pass window object:

```
var $ = require('jquery')(window);
```

But actually I don't need to do that and it still works:

What's the difference here?
Why it's so simple when I use them in a script tag, I only need to put them in the right order and it just work. 
Why I need to do some extra work when I use these libraries as commonjs module in node?

Answer (score 1):

Using script tags works fine, up to a point.  As you add new frontend libraries and new application specific code, managing the dependencies between them becomes really difficult.  When just using script tags, yes, you "just have to put them in the right order and it will just work."  That's ok if you just have a few scripts, but getting that right as your project grows is more challenging than you might think (I say this from experience).

As you noted, using CommonJS modules fixes this.  Dependencies are clearly noted with the `require` syntax, and exports with `module.exports`, and you can forget about managing dependencies and let the script loader do that.  It may seem like overhead at first, but it will let your project scale.  The upfront cost of getting a module system set up for your JS code will be worth it down the road.

Using a module system like CommonJS also encourages good encapsulation, which will help you write more reusable code components that are easier to maintain.

The other really big reason that you want to use a module based system for your JS code is that in production, you can bundle all your scripts together.  Using a tool like browserify, you can go through all of your scripts and bundle them together into one JS file, which means 1 HTTP request instead of a separate HTTP request for each script tag.  This almost always means that your page will load faster, especially on mobile where the latency for each HTTP request is really high.

The one caveat here is that *might* a good idea to include really popular libraries (like jQuery) in the page with a script tag (using a CDN copy) if you think it might be cached by the user's browser.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the nice explanation about the difference of using  script tag and commonjs. But that's not quite what I asked, my question is why I need to set Backbone.$ explicitly in commonjs instead of that it will take care of itself when used in a script tag.

Comment: Sorry for not answering your real question.  It's because when you load jQuery via the script tag, it sets the global `window.$` variable to be the jQuery object.  Libraries that depend on jQuery, like Backbone and Underscore, expect to find this global variable.  One of the huge benefits of CommonJS is that you don't muck up the global namespace with variables.  The only way to get the jQuery object is through a call to `require('jquery')`; the `window.$` variable is undefined.  So the line `Backbone.$ = $;` tells Backbone how to get jQuery without needing to grab it from the `window` object.